# A (weakly protected) secure server using GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: cocoa, ssl, ssl-certificate, gcdasyncsocket

I'm trying to use GCDAsyncSocket to write a weakly protected server (i.e. something I would be able to connect to using an anon cipher). What I'm currently doing is the following:

1. Bind to a port and start listening

   ```
   ...
   BOOL result = [serverSocket acceptOnPort:port error:&error];
   ...
   ```
2. Then, when a connection on the specified port arrives, I receive it in the `- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket` callback. Here I create a dictionary with my SSL/TLS settings:

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   NSArray* ciphers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA] , [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5] , [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384], [NSNumber
   numberWithUnsignedInt:TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5], nil]; //all anon ciphers

   [settings setObject:ciphers forKey:GCDAsyncSocketSSLCipherSuites];

   //this is a server
   [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString*)kCFStreamSSLIsServer];

   [newSocket startTLS:settings]; //apply the settings to new connection
   ```
3. After I apply the settings by calling `startTLS`, the `newSocket` disconnects, and the `- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)error` is getting called, the error code being 9800 (errSSLProtocol).

**The question: What am I doing wrong / not doing?**

My guess is that it is something to do with certificates which I'm not specifying. But do I need to specify a cert if I'm doing an anon cipher?

Comment: I don't think `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` is a real cipher, though it does have a point assigned to it by IANA (`{0x00,0x00}`). Its an initial state of the state machine.

Comment: Yeah, true. My bad. But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've finally figured it out. The code above is absolutely correct. The problem was that I was using an OpenSSL-based client to connect which was using SSLv2 by default. It turns out that SSLv2 has a buggy implementation in OpenSSL and therefore is not fully compatible with other implementations of the same protocol (e.g. the one by Apple), even though it communicates well with other components using OpenSSL. The problem was solved by forcing the client to use TLSv1 instead (even though it could have been SSLv3) which is implemented correctly.